# Complete sequences in $C[0,1]$ and $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

It is problem 1.5.4 in Robert M. Young's book, An introduction to nonharmonic Fourier series:

Show that if $\{f_1,f_2,\dots\}$ is a sequence in $C[0,1]$ that is complete in $L^2[0,1]$, then $\{1, f_1, f_2,\dots\}$ is complete in $C[0,1]$.

Completeness here means the set of finite linear combinations is dense.

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to be complete?

Comment: It means the set of finite linear combinations is dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false - is the problem in the book exactly the same as your question?

Say $e_k(t)=e^{ikt}$, and let $(f_n)$ be the sequence $(1,e_1,e_{-1},e_2,e_{-2}\dots)$. Then $(f_n)$ is certainly complete in $L^2([0,1])$. But if $f$ is a linear combination of $(1,f_1,f_2,\dots)$ then $f(1)=f(0)$,  and functions with this property are not dense in $C([0,1])$.

Regardless of exactly how the problem is stated in the book I conjecture that what the author really had in mind was  $L^2(\mathbb T)$ and $C(\mathbb T)$. It's false in that context as well, but the example is not so obvious:

A book on nonharmonic Fourier series probaby contains a proof of this:

> > Suppose $(f_n)$ is a complete orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space $H$ and $\sum||f_n-g_n||^2<1$. Then $(g_n)$ is also complete in $H$.

(Sketch of proof: Define $T:H\to H$ by $T\sum a_nf_n=\sum a_ng_n$. Then $||T-I||<1$, hence $T$ is invertible.)

Now let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct points of $\mathbb T$. Let $f_n$ be as above; choose $g_n\in C(\mathbb T)$ so that $g_n(a)=g_n(b)$ and $\sum||f_n-g_n||_2^2<1$. Then $(g_n)$ is complete in $L^2(\mathbb T)$ but $(1,g_1,\dots)$ is not complete in $C(\mathbb T)$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand this. Strictly speaking, isn't $C([0, 1])$ a subspace of $L^2([0, 1])$? How could a sequence in $C([0, 1])$ that is complete in $L^2([0, 1])$ not be complete in $C([0, 1])$? That would mean that there is a subset of $C([0, 1])$ that is dense in $L^2([0, 1])$ but not dense in $C([0, 1])\subsetneq L^2([0, 1])$.

Comment: The definition of "complete in $X$" depends on the _topology_ of $X$. Yes, $C([0,1])$ is a vector-space subspace of $L^2([0,1])$. But not a normed-vector-space subspace - the "default" topology on $C([0,1])$ is not the subspace topology. To be totally explicit: For any $f\in L^2$ there is $g$, a linear combination of the $f_n$, with $||f-g||_2<\epsilon$. But not $||f-g||_{C([0,1])}<\epsilon$.

Comment: Appreciate it, David! The problem is exactly the same as that in the book. But you are right.

Comment: Of course. That was silly of me. I had assumed from the wording that we were taking $C([0, 1])$ as a topological vector subspace of $L^2([0, 1])$. I can verify that the question is written here exactly as stated in the textbook (see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q7p94-ZVxg4C&lpg=PA18&vq=Complete&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false)).